# React in Routes shows up only one route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been trying to connect components to links, but whenever i write more than one route in `<Routes>`
react seems to ignore it, and does not respond to anything. Also used `<StrictMode>` to see what happens inside program
Here is my code:

```jsx
import {Routes,Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Teacher from "./pages/TeacherComponent";
import Navbar  from "./pages/Navbar";
import { StrictMode } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StrictMode>
    <div className="mx-12 my-4 rounded px-8 py-4 bg-fuchsia-100 h-full">
      <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*"  element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="teacher" element={<Teacher />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </StrictMode>

  );
};
```

[image: Screenshot from plugin analysing script]

I've tried changing react-router-dom version, to use `<Switch>`, but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Routes are normally processed in the order in which you define them. Here, you are having a catch-all route as the first entry `<Route path=*` . So, all routes will get matched to this, and always `Home` component will be displayed.

To fix this, switch the order of the route entries so that the most specific entries comes at the top

```js
 <Routes>
  <Route path="teacher" element={<Teacher />}/>
  <Route path="*"  element={<Home />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path prop in the second Route component should be **"/teacher"** instead of just **"teacher"**.

So just replace it and run again and I am sure it will work.

Do let me know how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add exact to each route, React won't ignore the path specified again.
thanks.....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).